# My gitlab keep getting 503 error, gitaly socket not exists

Tags: linux, gitlab, gitaly

I have a self hosted gitlab CE server ,running fine for a year now.

Just a few days ago this error keep poping up

Please help me fix this. I don’t know why the gitaly socket just keep delete and create every time

Gitlab Version: 12.0.12 (ce125b970e4)

OS: Centos 7 3.10.0-1160.11.1.el7.x86_64

```
Gitlab::Git::CommandError (14:all SubConns are in TransientFailure, latest connection error: connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial unix /tmp/gitaly-ruby289404666/socket.1: connect: no such file or directory"):
  lib/gitlab/git/wraps_gitaly_errors.rb:13:in `rescue in wrapped_gitaly_errors'
  lib/gitlab/git/wraps_gitaly_errors.rb:6:in `wrapped_gitaly_errors'
  lib/gitlab/git/blob.rb:83:in `batch_lfs_pointers'
  lib/extracts_path.rb:149:in `lfs_blob_ids'
  app/controllers/projects/application_controller.rb:98:in `block in allow_gitaly_ref_name_caching'
  lib/gitlab/gitaly_client.rb:309:in `allow_ref_name_caching'
  app/controllers/projects/application_controller.rb:97:in `allow_gitaly_ref_name_caching'
  lib/gitlab/session.rb:11:in `with_session'
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:445:in `set_session_storage'
  lib/gitlab/i18n.rb:55:in `with_locale'
  lib/gitlab/i18n.rb:61:in `with_user_locale'
  app/controllers/application_controller.rb:439:in `set_locale'
  lib/gitlab/middleware/multipart.rb:103:in `call'
  lib/gitlab/request_profiler/middleware.rb:16:in `call'
  lib/gitlab/middleware/go.rb:20:in `call'
  lib/gitlab/etag_caching/middleware.rb:13:in `call'
  lib/gitlab/middleware/correlation_id.rb:16:in `block in call'
  lib/gitlab/middleware/correlation_id.rb:15:in `call'
  lib/gitlab/middleware/read_only/controller.rb:40:in `call'
  lib/gitlab/middleware/read_only.rb:18:in `call'
  lib/gitlab/middleware/basic_health_check.rb:25:in `call'
  lib/gitlab/request_context.rb:26:in `call'
  lib/gitlab/metrics/requests_rack_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
  lib/gitlab/middleware/release_env.rb:12:in `call'
```

Comment: Is your installation from source or omnibus? Can you show any custom gitaly configurations you have? An easy way to solve this would be to upgrade GitLab since `gitaly-ruby` goes away altogether in later versions of gitlab.

Comment: @sytech I use omnibus installation,  I don't config gitaly anywhere. In fact I don't know about gitaly until now. I will try to upgrade to see if it fix. It really strange

Comment: If I had to guess, the problem probably arises out of using `/tmp` for the gitaly sockets. On Fedora systems, tempfs (`/tmp`) is cleared periodically by a cron job. However, the gitaly socket location is not configurable until version 12.6 with the `internal_socket_dir` configuration option (and its default changes away from `/tmp` it seems) [related issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitaly/-/issues/1564). But gitaly-ruby also goes away in GitLab 14.x -- other possible solution may be to increase number of gitaly-ruby workers. (beware you cant upgrade directly to 14.x; follow upgrade path)